# The set of largest numbers definable by formulas in different lengths

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, computability-theory

Let $n=\phi(l)$ to be the largest number definable by a first order arithmetic formula $f(x)$ having length at most $l$. By "$n$ is definable by formula $f(x)$" I mean $\mathcal{N}\vDash f(a)$ iff $a=n$, where $\mathcal{N}$ is a structure of natural numbers with the standard interpretation (if it's necessary to be specific, think of it as $\mathcal{N}=\{\mathbb{N}|+,*,1\}$). This function  is well-defined. My question is, how fast does it grow? Can we put it in some appropriate framework and say something more about it?

One observation I can make is that no first order arithmetic formula defines the function $n=\phi(l)$, i.e., there exists no formula $\psi(x,y)$ such that $\mathcal{N}\vDash \psi(n,l)$ iff $n=\phi(l)$. This means the set $\{n,l|n=\phi(l)\}$ is beyond arithmetic hierarchy, where I have only very limited knowledge.

---

Edit: Issues mentioned in the comments are addressed.

Comment: "Definable by a formula in a theory" is unclear.  A formula of first-order arithmetic has a meaning in $\mathbb{N}$ (the natural model) without any reference to a theory.  Do you mean to impose that the theory proves the existence of a unique $n$ satisfying the formula, or something of the sort?

Comment: I don’t see how this is well-defined either. Even if the theory proves there exists a unique $n$ satisfying the formula, this does not mean that it gives it a definite finite value. For example, consider the formula “$x$ is the length of the shortest proof of contradiction in PA, or $0$ if no such proof exists”. Then PA proves that this formula defines a unique integer, but it does not prove its value to be equal to any fixed numeral.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen,Emil, you are correct. I edited the question and hopefully it'll be more clear to understand now.

Comment: An EXPLICIT definition would be fun! We'd have an ever growing table of records. And more people would bother to think about your strategic question on the whole function.

Comment: Let a formula $\ f_k(x)\ $ be of the form: $\ x = (1+1+1)*(1+1+1)*(1+1+1)*(1+1+1)\ $ (here the case of $\ k:=4\ $ is presented). Do we get anything much better than this?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński, in your case k=33 (every symbol counts if by k you mean the length of the formula), and the number definable by your formula in that length is 81.

Comment: The length of formula $\ f_k(x)\ $ is $\ L=6\cdot k+1\ $ (this includes symbols $\ =\ $ and $\ x)\, $ while the defined value $\ N\ $ is $\ 3^k.\ $ Thus $\ N\ $ is almost $ (3^\frac L6).\ $ Is $ n = \phi(L) $ clearly larger than $\ 3^\frac L6\ $ for L large?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten about parenthesis. I should use the Łukasiewicz notation: 111++111++*111++*111++*x!

Comment: If parentheses count then instead of $\ 3^\frac L6\ $ I should have $\ 3^\frac L8.\ $ However, in general, it's useful to attach weights to each symbol. In the case of pure logic, it'd be natural to attach weights 1 to the true (meaningful) symbols, and 0 to parentheses. In less pure applications the weights may depend on the applications as it should for instance in the case of computer hardware design.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me interpret the question asking about what is true in the
standard model $\langle\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}\N,+,\cdot,0,1,<\rangle$, which
avoids the non-absoluteness issues mentioned in the comments. In
this case, the definition is well-defined and sensible. We define that $\Phi(n)$
is the largest number $m$ definable in the structure by a formula
of length at most $n$.

I view the topic here as an analogue of the busy-beaver problem for arithmetic truth.

**Theorem.** The function $\Phi(n)$ eventually dominates every
arithmetically definable function.

**Proof.** Suppose that $f:\N\to\N$ is an arithmetically definable
function, so that the relation $f(x)=y$ is definable in the
structure by some formula $\varphi(x,y)$.

Notice that with the powers of two, we can easily define large
numbers with comparatively small formulas. For example, $2^n$ is
definable by a formula of size $n+c$ for some constant $c$. Put
differently, and by iterating this, for any sufficiently large $k$
we can define a number $k^+$ larger than $k$ with a formula smaller than
$\log(\log(k))$.

Therefore, if $k$ is very large with respect to these constants and
the size of the definition of $f$, then we can define $\max_{x\leq
k^+}f(x)$ using a formula of size less than $k$. Thus,
$f(k)\leq\Phi(k)$, as desired. **QED**

Meanwhile, the function is Turing computable from $0^{(\omega)}$,
the $\omega$-jump of the halting problem, since that oracle is able
to compute first-order arithmetic truth. So you have a function
that is not computable from any finite jump $0^{(n)}$, but it is
computable from the $\omega$-jump.

I claim that the converse is also true. Your function is
essentially equivalent to arithmetic truth.

**Theorem.** The function $\Phi$ you have defined is Turing
equivalent to an oracle for arithmetic truth.

**Proof.** I've already pointed out that $\Phi$ is computable from
arithmetic truth.

Conversely, suppose that we have an oracle for your function
$\Phi$. I claim that we can compute arithmetic truth. The reason is
that we shall be able to compute Skolem witnesses. For example, to
compute the halting problem for a program $p$ on input $n$, we need
only express the formula "$y$ is the length of the compution of $p$
on $n$" and then apply the function $\Phi$ to get an upper bound
for the length of the computation. If the program doesn't halt by
then, then it won't ever halt, since the length of the computation
is definable.

We can systematically iterate this idea up the arithmetic
hierarchy. Namely, working from the atomic formulas up, every
assertion $\exists x\
\varphi(x,\dots)$ is replaced with the assertion $\exists
x<\Phi(k)\
\varphi(x,\dots)$, where $k$ is the size of the expression
appearing to the right. By using a term for $\Phi(k)$, and iteratively applying this procedure to higher quantifiers, in the case that they were nested, we thereby get a computable expression that is equivalent to the original
formula. In this way, arithmetic truth reduces to a computable
process with the function $\Phi$. **QED**

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question while you were answering it, as you interpret it.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after having posted. Nice question! I think the busy-beaver analogy may be a fruitul perspective, since the argument that BB is not computable and is Turing equivalent to the halting problem is basically similar to the arguments I gave that your function is not arithmetic and is Turing equivalent to arithmetic truth.

Comment: I don't understand the last paragraph. If both $\varphi(n_1)$ and $\varphi(n_2)$ are true, then neither $n_1$ or $n_2$ is defined by $\varphi$, and either one of them could be bigger than $\Phi(k)$, because $\Phi(k)$ applies only to the case where $\varphi(n)$ is true for a single n.

Comment: The point is that the least $n$ for which $\varphi(n)$ holds will be definable. The standard model has definable Skolem functions---there are always definable witnesses for existential assertions, since you can take the least one, and that one is definable by being least.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, so let me put it this way. By "n is definable" I mean $\mathcal{N}\vDash f(a)$ iff $a=n$. But did you mean by "n is definable"  $\mathcal{N}\vDash f(n)$ and $\mathcal{N}\vDash f(m)$ only if $m \ge n$? The latter definition allows larger $n$ to be defined for the same formula length.

Comment: We have the same understanding of what it means to be definable. I am saying that if you have an existential assertion $\exists x\varphi(x)$, then the least such $x$, if there is one, is definable. It is the unique $x$ such that $\varphi(x)\wedge \forall y<x\ \neg\varphi(y)$.  In this way, we can use your function $\Phi$ to help us bound our existential searches, thereby making them computable.  Since it takes a few symbols to say that $x$ is least, in my proof, you have to let $k$ be a little bigger than just what comes after: let it be the size of what it takes to describe the least witness.

Comment: Nice answer. Do you think if Goodstein function would outgrow $\Phi$?

Comment: @FFF, Goodstein squence is computable, hence definable in first order arithmetic. It's way below $\Phi$, which is not definable in first order arithmetic.

Comment: If the $\exists x \varphi(x,\dots)$ in your last paragraph is $\exists x \forall y f(x,y)$, how do we get rid of the $\forall y$ part and make it computable?